# The "ReportDataSource" keyword doesn't show in the Intell what's wrong with it?

Tags: c#

```
ReportDataSource rds =new ReportDataSource("Orders", ds.Tables[0]);
```

The "ReportDataSource" keyword doesn't show in the Intell what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

You must import the applicable namespace, depending on the UI framework you're using.

```
// For instance:
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
// Or:
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate preview, and I can't find or add "using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;" or "using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;" in C# WebForm Website Project. Please explain for me why?
And I looking for these namespaces on MSDN, but I can find reference on Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010, but I can't find reference on later version.

Comment: Solution exp»Right click Reference and click  Add find the Microsoft.Reporting.
WebForms on the lists then add it.